# Error compiling against Yojson

Tags: json, ocaml

I have import for Yojson in my code

```
open Yojson.Basic.Util
```

and following in Make file

```
eval `opam config env` && ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind voigt.native
```

I'm getting error `"Unbound module Yojson"`, while compiling

```
eval `opam config env` && ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind voigt.native
ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -o config.cmx config.ml
+ ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -o config.cmx config.ml
File "config.ml", line 1, characters 5-22:
Error: Unbound module Yojson
Command exited with code 2.
```

When I use utop everything works. What should I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify, that you want to use `yojson`. Assuming, that the package name is `yojson` the correct command would be:

```
ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg yojson voigt.native
```

And on modern installations you even do not require to use `-use-ocamlfind` flag, as it should work even without this.

Comment: Yes, that helped! Is there any way to derive *automagically* list of packages that should be included?

Comment: nope, but it can be much simplified with `oasis` tool.